# Passing Flags in XCODE

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, wxwidgets

I have configure wxWidgets in my MAC OS. In terminal my program in working fine. Here is the following command which I use to run.

`gcc -o main main.cpp -I/usr/lib/wx/include/mac-unicode-debug-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXDEBUG__ -D__WXMAC__  -framework IOKit -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework System -framework QuickTime -framework OpenGL -framework AGL  -lwx_macud-2.8`

How can I configure xcode so that it pass the Header & libs to GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XCode, bring up the Inspector for the target, look at the "Build" tab, search for "header" and "library". You'll find the relevant configuration options.